# How to handle invalidated object / object invalidation safely?

Tags: design-patterns, invalidation

Builder pattern is can be used to handle validation of object like this:

```
class WebSocketConnectionBuilder {
    constructor(public readonly url: string) {

    }
    connect(): Promise<WebSocketConnection> {
        const ws = new WebSocket(this.url);

        return new Promise((solve, reject) => {
            ws.onopen = () => {
                solve(new WebSocketConnection(ws));
            }
            ws.onerror = (error) => {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It is safer than normal `WebSocket` object, because we can assure that connection has been established when we have `WebSocketConnection` object. We can validate the fact "the connection is established" from presence of `WebSocketConnection` object.

However, when this connection closed, I can't invalidate `WebSocketConnection` object to make be not able to use it. Once the object created, the object become valid permanently on perspective of type system. What I can do is just "throw error" when method about connection called in wrong time(i.e. connection closed).

I'm sorry to be not able to describe what exactly I want to do, but I'll be thankful to any answer or idea of safer way to invalidate object. Any programming language is ok.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, if you are creating an object `WebSocketConnection` when `onopen` event is fired, then it means that you have a link to this newly created object:

```
ws.onopen = () => {
    solve(new WebSocketConnection(ws));
}
```

So when you close sonnection, you can send this link to `onclose` event and do what you want with that object. So code would look something like this:

```
ws.onclose = (WebSocketConnection socket) => {
    socket.isValid = false;
}
```